# how to improve site speed & optimise images for browsers

Tags: optimization, web

How I can improve site speed and to optimize images size and quality wise for internet browsers mainly for IE. pleas give me step by step approach so I can implement it in easy way. Answer only if you have done this before.

site : http://www.bravorentacardubai.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, i think you should express your needs in a different tone, as no one is SO owes you an answer. Everyone have their own things to do and is just trying to offer help to those that need it.

Next, you can try https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ google will tell you what you can optimize.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, it is an x-ray report of my website speed factors.